# Why didn't C++0x deprecate implicit conversions?

Tags: c++11, implicit-conversion

Why didn't C++0x deprecate implicit conversions for user defined types a.k.a. objects? Is there any project which actually uses this (mis)feature? Whenever I see a single argument constructor in a code I get to review or modify I treat it as bug and make it explicit. So far it worked well and nobody complained.

Thank you.

EDIT: Let me quote Alex Stepanov, the creator of STL:

> Open your C++ book and read about the
>   explicit keyword! Also petition your
>   neighborhood C++ standard committee
>   member to finally abolish implicit
>   conversions. There is a common
>   misconception, often propagated by
>   people who should know better, that
>   STL depends on implicit conversions.
>   Not so!

Reference: [A. Stepanov. C++ notes](http://www.stepanovpapers.com/notes.pdf)

EDIT AGAIN: No, no debate plz. I am just curious whether anyone uses implicit conversions in their work. I never seen any project which would allow implicit conversion for objects. I thought hard and couldn't come with any hypothetical scenario where implicit conversion wouldn't become a minefield. I mean C++ single argument conversions, not float->double or similar conversions inherited from C.

Comment: You never pass a string literal to a function with an argument of type `std::string`?

Comment: Could std::string be made an exception? It belongs to C++ standard and compiler could treat it differently. Do you know anyone who uses implicit conversion for user defined types? I see people are using explicit keyword everywhere, even in multiple argument constructors. Many people make every constructor explicit, just in case, because it doesn't hurt. But implicit conversion can hurt badly.

Comment: Much of the allure of C++ is that libraries are pretty much equal, whether it's the standard library or user-defined libraries.  I don't want special treatment of `std::string`, I want to be able to download someone's `utf8string` class and have it function just as smoothly as `std::string`.

Comment: Why would someone downvote or close this question? IMO it's a valid one, even though the answer is simple. (Implicit conversions is something we inherited from C, which introduced it 40 years ago, and which was expanded int C++' type system almost 30 years ago. While those who designed C and C++ that way would most likely not do this again, we're now stuck with billions of lines of working code relying on this, which we can't break.)

Comment: @sbi: If the language were redesigned from scratch, I don't think implicit conversions would be gone.  There might not be implicit implicit conversions, instead requiring an `implicit` keyword as Ronald's answer mentions.  But there is no good reason that widening conversions should not remain implicit.

Comment: @Ben: Yeah, maybe. IMO that's open to debate. Unfortunately, this debate was clamped down here. For no good reason, if you ask me.

Comment: @sbi: That's exactly why this question was closed: because it invites debate rather than (or in addition to) an objective answer.  If you feel that SO should be a forum for debate, best bring that up on meta.

Comment: @Ben: There's an obvious answer to the actual question, which requires no debate at all, and which you provided yourself. What we debated was whether, for some hypothetical new language that doesn't need to respect the gazillions of line of code C++ inherited, implicit conversions would be good or not. That debate actually now takes place in our comments just as it would have had the question not been closed, so closing the question was not relevant to it.

Comment: @pic11 offtopic observation: in English you write "Why didn't C++ ...?", not "Why C++ didn't ...?"  I tweaked it for you.

Answer (score 7):

The obvious answer is that code written and working in C++03 is supposed to continue working with C++0x compilers.

Comment: Deprecated doesn't mean removed.

Comment: [We don't know what it means](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#223).

Comment: They already have made sure that some c++03 code will no longer run. http://cpp-next.com/archive/2011/02/w00t-w00t-nix-nix/

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, it would be a hugely breaking change to remove implicit conversion from the language - even if it were made optional and off-by-default with an `implicit` keyword.

I've done a search of comp.std.c++ and it doesn't seem to have been discussed at all in that group - though there have been some questions on the subject, no-one seems to have suggested going so far as removing it. I would certainly not go so far either: it's a feature I happily use on occasion and I do not subscribe to making all possibly-converting constructors `explicit` either - unless it causes real bugs.

Comment: Instead of introducing another keyword, you *could* use `!explicit` ;)

Comment: @Fred wouldn't `~explicit` be more their style?

Comment: @Kit: Good suggestion, I like it :)